# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 401 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, spell-checking

I have been trying to implement spell check by using the bing spell check api. I am getting a 401 error. The error is

*No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.*

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function hi(){


        var params = {
            // Request parameters
            "mode": "{Spell}",
        };

        $.ajax({
             url: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?" + $.param(params),
             beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","{0c6cb56a997b41d4958ace895a677729}");
            },
        crossDomain: false,
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'jsonp',

            // Request body
                data: {
            dataSpell: $("#textContent").val()},

        success : function(result){
            $("div").html(result); }
        //dataType: 'jsonp'
    });


    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textContent" spell-check="true" placeholder="Type here"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="spellcheck" onclick="hi();" >Click Me!</button>
<div> </div>
</body>

</html>​
```

Comment: you cannot send request to one website from webscript of another website unless the 3rd party website explicitly whitelist you. You should read about `Cross Domain Resource Sharing (CORS)`

Answer (score 1):

> {...} you are doing an XMLHttpRequest to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request.

Quoting answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource), so check it out if you are still confused about why you are getting this error. You can learn how to bypass this using [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) here.